# ¿Cómo hacer una barra de texto en movimiento?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

¿Podrían guiarme sobre cómo hacer un slider de varios `<p>` que se muevan infinitamente?

Por ejemplo, tengo un `<div>` rectangular, y en este `div` tengo 16 etiquetas `<p>` colocadas en línea después de hacer flexible al `div` con `display:flex`, he hecho una animación para que el primer `<p>` se mueva de derecha a izquierda, pero llega un momento en que se cumple el tiempo de animación y el texto se detiene.

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando el primer `<p>` tenga más o menos un `margin-left` de -120%, el primer `<p>` se coloque detrás del último y así el segundo `<p>` pasaría a tomar el primer lugar y también cuando tenga -120% de `margin-left`, éste se posicione detrás del último, y así sucesivamente dando un movimiento infinito (el -120% de `margin-left` es solo un valor de ejemplo):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo es:

```js
$('#cadenaEtiquetas p:first').animate({
  'margin-left': '-130%'
}, 90000);
```

```css
#cadenaEtiquetas {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #A09F9F;
}

#cadenaEtiquetas p:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 100%;
}

#cadenaEtiquetas p {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cadenaEtiquetas">
  <p>Texto1</p>
  <p>Texto2</p>
  <p>Texto3</p>
  <p>Texto4</p>
  <p>Texto5</p>
  <p>Texto6</p>
  <p>Texto7</p>
  <p>Texto8</p>
  <p>Texto9</p>
  <p>Texto10</p>
  <p>Texto11</p>
  <p>Texto12</p>
  <p>Texto13</p>
  <p>Texto14</p>
  <p>Texto15</p>
  <p>Texto16</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sería bueno que explicaras qué has intentado y con qué problemas te has encontrado. Además, ¿quieres que todos los `p` salgan seguidos? ¿o uno solo cada vez? Si es todos seguidos, ¿quieres que quede un espacio en blanco entre el último y que empiece de nuevo el primero?

Comment: He intentado lo que puse en el codigo, por favor ejecutalo para q veas como funciona, todo esta bien, salvo que quiero q sea infinito

Comment: Ejecutalo aqui mismo, tal como sale esta bien, pero quiero q sea infinito, y para que sea infinito,cada uno de los <P> que salen deben irse al final cada cierto tiempo.

Comment: No se si no me entiendes, he intentado hacerlo usando insertAfter() pero no resulta lo que quiero

Answer (score 2):

```css
.con-animate {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    height: 50px;
    overflow:hidden
    }
    .con-animate > div {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      background: rgb(255, 255, 255);

    }
    .con-animate > div p {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .con-animate > .animate1 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      animation: animate1 linear 10s infinite;
      transform: translate(0);
    }
    .con-animate > .animate2 {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      animation: animate2 linear 10s infinite;
      transform: translate(0);
    }
    @keyframes animate1 {
    from {transform:translate(0%)}
    to {transform:translate(-100%)}
    }
    @keyframes animate2 {
    from {transform:translate(100%)}
    to {transform:translate(0%)}
    }
```

```html
<div class="con-animate">
    <div class="animate1">
      <p>Texto1</p>
      <p>Texto2</p>
      <p>Texto3</p>
      <p>Texto4</p>
      <p>Texto5</p>
      <p>Texto6</p>
      <p>Texto7</p>
      <p>Texto8</p>
      <p>Texto9</p>
      <p>Texto10</p>
      <p>Texto11</p>
      <p>Texto12</p>
      <p>Texto13</p>
      <p>Texto14</p>
      <p>Texto15</p>
      <p>Texto16</p>
    </div>
    <div class="animate2">
      <p>Texto1</p>
      <p>Texto2</p>
      <p>Texto3</p>
      <p>Texto4</p>
      <p>Texto5</p>
      <p>Texto6</p>
      <p>Texto7</p>
      <p>Texto8</p>
      <p>Texto9</p>
      <p>Texto10</p>
      <p>Texto11</p>
      <p>Texto12</p>
      <p>Texto13</p>
      <p>Texto14</p>
      <p>Texto15</p>
      <p>Texto16</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

cuando la animación de uno termine lo poner en el inicio y el otro es el que el usuario esta viendo es un ciclo

Comment: como lo harias? usarias insertAfter()??

Comment: pones una animacion normal con un tiempo ejemplo 1s y le pasas un timeOut de 1s cuando pase el tiempo lo pones en el inicio osea 0% y inicias la otra animacion

Comment: listo amigo @Mariano gracias por el dato